# Windows Phone: How to load html in webview from a local file

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a html string and it has local css,js paths. But Html is not working with these local paths. We searced but in every example, they have loaded html with writing inline. But I have to work disconnect and there is so much css,js assests. If i write inline, i am worried about it will load slow and i think it so senseless. Then i decided to change a local html file and load html from that file.

How can i load html from a local file?

This is my example code:

```
   StorageFolder localFolder =
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;


           string desiredName = "mobile.html";
           StorageFile newFile =
               await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName,CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

           using (var stream = await newFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                  {
                      stream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                  }

             webViewFormResponse.Source = new Uri(newFile.Path);
```

`newFile.Path` like this: `C:\Data\Users\DefApps\APPDATA\Local\Packages\9f4082ad-ad69-4cb8-8749-751ee4c5e46d_x2xndhe6jjw20\LocalState\mobile.html`

Comment: Read the html file into a string and use NavigateToString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the NavigateToLocalStreamUri method of the WebView

e.g.

In WebView Loaded event

```
private void WebView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    Uri uri = MyWebView.BuildLocalStreamUri("LocalData", "mobile.html");
    LocalUriResolver resolver = new LocalUriResolver();
    MyWebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(uri, resolver);
}
```

And the Uri resolver class

```
public sealed class LocalUriResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
    {
        public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
        {
            if (uri == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            string path = uri.AbsolutePath;
            return GetContent(path).AsAsyncOperation();
        }

        private async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string uriPath)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri localUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local" + uriPath);
                StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri);
                IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                return stream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid path");
            }
        }
    }
```